# Apply function to several directories

Tags: r

I have a directory (say, `/Users/clemk/`) full of some more directories `dir_1, dir_2, ..., dir_n`. Each of those directories has a csv file named `data.csv`.
I would like to apply `my_function()` to each data.csv, and use the name of the directory each data.csv is in (i.e dir1, ..., dir_n) to name something within `my_function`.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not super clear what you are asking. Hopefully this helps...

```
root <- "/Users/clemk/"
dirs <- c("dir_1", "dir_2", ..., "dir_n")
# or dirs <- paste0("dir_", 1:n)
lapply(dirs, function(x)my_function(paste0(root, x, "/data.csv")))
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for answering. I think I finally figured my whole problem out and even though I did not use explicitely what you wrote, it helped me to get where I am now :) Have a good day!